# I can't get Autocomplete get to work with AngularJS, NodeJS, mssql

Tags: angularjs, sql-server, node.js

Hi I'm new to AngularJS and I'm trying to fetch data from my DB to my controller to create Autocomplete Search Bar.
Here is my code were I'm connecting to my DB and collect the data that I need:

```
    router.get('/request', function (req, res) {
    connection.then(function(){ //connection is my sql.connect to the confing
       new sql.Request().query("SELECT FullName from Employee").then(function(recordset){
            res.render('request',{json: JSON.stringify(recordset)});       
       }).catch(function(err){
           console.log("Connection Error " + err);
       });
    });
});
```

Here is my controller code:

```
app.controller('autocompleteCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    var self = this;

    self.data = null;
    self.selectedItem = null;
    self.searchText = null;


    self.querySearch = function(){
        $http.get('/users/request').then(function(result){
            self.data = result.data.Search;
            return result.data.Search;
        });
    }
}]);
```

Here is the code inside the view:

```
<md-autocomplete md-floating-label="Employee name" 
                            flex="" 
                            md-item-text="item.FullName"
                            md-items="item in ctrl.data" 
                            md-search-text-change="ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
                            md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" 
                            md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem" 
                            md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache" 
                            md-input-maxlength="30" 
                            md-input-minlength="3" 
                            md-input-name="autocompleteField" 
                            required="">
              <md-item-template>
                <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText">{{item.FullName}}</span>
              </md-item-template>
              <div ng-messages="searchForm.autocompleteField.$error" ng-if="searchForm.autocompleteField.$touched">
                <div ng-message="required">You <b>must</b> have a favorite movie.</div>
                <div ng-message="minlength">Your entry is not long enough.</div>
                <div ng-message="maxlength">Your entry is too long.</div>
              </div>
            </md-autocomplete>
```

When I'm trying to type inside the search bar it gives me the error :

> Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

I don't know how to do this... Please help me !
Thanks!

Comment: To get more chances for response, I would upload a working example somewhere, and specify where exactly in the code you get the error. I recently had that error here: https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/autocomplete/js/autocompleteController.js#L773 I don't know anymore how I solved it, but looking at your code, I'd try to set the data to some initial value [].

Comment: As said by raichu, you need to provide some more info about the code where error occurs. But still I think the error is at your http call `$http.get('/users/request')`. check response of that call under `network` tab of browsers developer console. most probably there is a server side issue in `node.js` code, either it is not sending any data or failing totally.